# Sugarcrm module Subpanel create dosent trigger hook

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm, sugarbean

I am working in the hook. When I create a record from subpanel it doesn't trigger the hook. But when I use `link existing record` the hook is executing. Which hook should we use when `create` from a subpanel.

```
$hook_array['after_relationship_add'][] = array(
    1,
    'after relationship hook',
    'custom/modules/Records/Hooks/LinkedRecord.php',
    'Records_Hooks_LinkedRecord',
    'linkedRecords',
);
```

Community Link: https://community.sugarcrm.com/message/94290-subpanel-create-dosent-trigger-hook

Comment: What kind of code are you running when the relationship is added? In other words, in what context is your hook? Is this hook on the parent, or the child?

Comment: I found the solution @Reisclef will post the answer. The hook should be create module then the display module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger your code on creation of record then you will need to use *after_save* and *before_save* logic hooks. See this link for further details: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/

Last but not least, create from module or sub-panel trigger same hooks (after and before) so no difference in creation from sub-panel and module.

Hopefully provided documentation is clear enough.

Comment: I found the solution, will post the answer. The hook should be in create module then the display module

Comment: Yes you are right about your mentioned point as well. You know if you want to trigger hook then module should be enabled so that sugar can use it.